# Using magick-wasm without node.js?

Tags: javascript, image, imagemagick

I'm trying to import [magick.wasm](https://github.com/dlemstra/magick-wasm) to use within my own javascript, without using node.js - but it doesn't seem to be working.

Downloading the library gives me 4 files:

`index.d.ts`,
`index.mjs`,
`index.umd.js` and `magick.wasm`

I have my HTML like so to see if the Magick functions are being imported:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Magick-WASM Example</title>
    <script type='module'>
        //import the library to talk to imagemagick
        import * as Magick from './index.umd.js';
        console.log(Object.keys(Magick));
      </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

but the array is returning empty. I must be doing something wrong. Is there any way to do this without using npm/node.js?